# A js file on heroku returns <h3> instead of the content

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

```
# application.html.erb
!!!
%html
  %head
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = yield :head



# my_view.html.haml
= content_for :head do
  %script{src: asset_path('my.js')}


# application.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << 'my.js'

#production.rb
config.serve_static_files = true
```

On heroku when I go to http://my_app.herokuapp.com/my.js it return only `<h3>` (literally), whereas on localhost everything is working fine.

The result html on heroku:

```
<script src='/my.js'></script>
```

What's up with that?

Comment: there should be another href to your asset after precompiling. something like  ../assets/my-78fd9eecdeff770cdb40772f9c904960.js. You can get the href from inspection of html at /my_view page

Comment: in what dir is your my.js file, app/assets/javascripts or /public ?

Comment: @TienNguyen, app/assets/javascripts